# Problem with saving the file (ASP.NET, Angular)

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs

I create an application using three kinds of technology ASP.NET, MVC, and AngularJS.

The back-end contains one page of `.aspx` and one file of the controller (and some `.cs` files). The front-end is AngularJS and jQuery. The problem is when I try to save something to the file on the server (no matter what and no matter where the save function is called). After saving (file is saved on the server), the application seems like it went OFF.
Communication with REST service is not available. Timers are stopped. I don't have any errors in `debug.Event` logs; they are empty. After refreshing the page by using the <kbd>F5</kbd> key, they all worked again.

Below is my sample code. If the function `WriteAllText` is called, the timer is stopped, REST is not available. I have tried to save the file using streamwriter but the result is the same.

Where is the problem?

```cs
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText(path, "test");
    if(Logic.customImages != null)
    SaveCache<List<CustomImage>>(Logic.customImages, "List<CustomImage>");
}
```

I check permissions of the folder for the network service. The path is correct. Files are saving no problem. There is no slowness. Unfortunatley, when I call the function containing any save file, then this action stops other actions from the controller. Below is action list.

1. Call the function by click from angularjs. Angular sends the post request to codebehind (call function where is save file) REST controller. All is correct. Response is successful. Save file is done.
2. After 1st action i call another function by click from angular js. Angular sends the post request to the codebehind REST controller. And here I have a problem . I have got a 404 error response (function is not available). But the function exists.
   If I remove the save file on 1st function, the 2nd function is a successful response.

I try to save the file another way using StreamWriter. But this does not resolve the problem. I don't know what is wrong. I encounter this kind of problem for the first time.

Comment: Using a timer to save a file seems strange. Could you show a bit more of the whole "file saving" process (like how is this timer-handler activated)?

Comment: Where exactly are you saving the file to? A network path may be unavailable and lead to timeouts

Comment: Saving in the timer is a sample. I coulde save file in other place but resoult be the same.

Comment: When saving to a file, most common issue is if the path is accessible to the application. Does the path already exist and does the app account have network access to it? Is there a network connectivity issue such as slowness or whatnot? Your problem seem to be isolated to `File.WriteAllText(path, "test");` or other forms of file access.